# How to strip punctuation from a text file

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import collections
import string
with open('cipher.txt') as f:
  f = f.read().replace(' ', '').replace('\n','').lower()
  f = f.strip(string.punctuation)

cnt = collections.Counter(f.replace(' ', ''))
for letter in sorted(cnt):
  print(letter, cnt[letter])
```

How do I strip the punctuation!! I can't figure out where to place that line?
Can someone please modify my code to remove everything apart from letters? thank you

Comment: The `strip` method only removes characters from the beginning and end of strings. Also, I would think it is a bad idea to open something as `f` and then reassign `f`.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary: Interesting, that page has no Python 3 solution. I added one.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [`str.translate()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate) to remove codepoints; any codepoint mapping to `None` is removed:

```
remove = dict.fromkeys(map(ord, '\n ' + string.punctuation))
f.translate(remove)
```

The `dict.fromkeys()` class method makes it easy to create a dictionary mapping all keys to `None`.

Demo:

```
>>> import string
>>> remove = dict.fromkeys(map(ord, '\n ' + string.punctuation))
>>> sample = 'The quick brown fox, like, totally jumped, man!'
>>> sample.translate(remove)
'Thequickbrownfoxliketotallyjumpedman'
```

Adjusted to your code:

```
remove = dict.fromkeys(map(ord, '\n ' + string.punctuation))

with open('cipher.txt') as inputfile:
    f = inputfile.read().translate(remove)
```

Comment: how do I implement this into my code? :)

Comment: @samir: Exactly as I posted it.

Comment: is there a way to remove all numbers as well? sorry for all the questions :/

Comment: @samir: It's easy enough to add `string.digits` to the set of characters removed, isn't it? I already show how to concatenate multiple strings in the sample code.

Comment: `string.punctuation + string.digits` still doesn't work?

Comment: @samir: *How* doesn't that work? It certainly works for me.

Comment: `remove = dict.fromkeys(map(ord, '\n ' + string.punctuation + string.digits))`

Comment: i added a '0' but it still prints out as the first item, how come?